# Using require_once in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

How do I use the `require_once` php function in Codeigniter on a normal PHP file? I', currently getting an error.

**Code:**

`require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/php/jformer.php');`

**Error:**

`Message: require_once() [function.require-once]: http:// wrapper is disabled in the server configuration by allow_url_include=0`

`Message: require_once(http://localhost/site/php/jformer.php) [function.require-once]: failed to open stream: no suitable wrapper could be found`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You don't use `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` for this, you want to use `APPPATH` or `BASEPATH` instead, or just type the full path to the file.  `require_once` should be passed a local file, not a URL.

Answer (score 3):

You should be using the path to the file and not the URL. Best (and certainly CI friendly) way would be to use `BASEPATH` or `APPPATH` constants.